# Identifying duplicates in a list of character vectors in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a list of character vectors like this:

```
my_list <- list(c('a','b','c','d','e'),c('e','f','g'),c('h','i','j'))
names(my_list) <- c("group1","group2","group3")
```

And I want to have a simple way to test `my_list` for duplicates in the letters across any of the 3 groups/vectors in my list.  So for instance, "e" appears in both group 1 and group 2 so that would be a duplicate.  Anything simple that just returns a logical if there is at least one or more duplicates across 2 or more groups would be ideal.  So a FALSE return would mean that the letters in each group are unique to that group only (this isn't the case in my example here obviously).

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A binary output can be generated with

```
any(duplicated(unlist(my_list)))
[1] TRUE
```

As pointed out correctly in comments by @sindri_baldur, if duplicates appear in groups they should be handled with `unique`, if desired:

```
any(duplicated(unlist(lapply(my_list, unique))))
[1] TRUE
```

or another **base R** alternative

```
anyDuplicated(unlist(lapply(my_list, unique))) > 1
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: `anyDuplicated(unlist(my_list)) > 0` should be more efficient. Also if duplicates are allowed within a vector you would have to start with: `lapply(my_list, unique)`.

Comment: @sindri_baldur True, we should guarantee uniques within a group, if desired! Will give it as an option, thx!

Comment: Thank you both!  And @Andre Wildberg, I appreciate the logic output.  This helps me with a if statement my code requires.

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
subset(stack(my_list), duplicated(values))$values
[1] "e"
```

If you need to tell whether all the values in a group are unique to that group, you could do:

```
result <- setNames(logical(length(my_list)), names(my_list))

result[unique(unlist(Filter(\(x)length(x)>1,
                            unstack(rev(stack(my_list))))))] <- TRUE
result
group1 group2 group3 
  TRUE   TRUE  FALSE
```

or even:

```
stack(my_list) %>%
  mutate(dups = duplicated(values) | duplicated(values, f = T)) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>%
  summarise(logic = any(dups))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ind    logic
  <fct>  <lgl>
1 group1 TRUE 
2 group2 TRUE 
3 group3 FALSE
```

Comment: With `dplyr` : 
`stack(my_list) %>% filter(duplicated(values)) %>% select(values)`

Comment: Thank you @Onyambu!  I'm actually using this as well to report specific values that are repeated.

Comment: You can also write `dups = values %in% values[duplicated(values)]`, which will work for more than 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

We can `stack` the named `list` to a two column data.frame, get the frequency count with `table`, check for duplicates by column with `colSums` on a logical vector and return with the `names` that are occuring more than 1

```
names(which(colSums(table(stack(my_list)[2:1])> 0) > 1))
[1] "e"
```

---

Or slighly more compact

```
 names(which(table(unlist(my_list)) > 1))
[1] "e"
```

---

If we want a logical column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
enframe(my_list) %>%
   unnest(value) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>%
   mutate(flag = any(n_distinct(name) > 1)) %>% 
 group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(flag = any(flag))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name   flag 
  <chr>  <lgl>
1 group1 TRUE 
2 group2 TRUE 
3 group3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, based on `tidyr::expand_grid` and `purrr::pmap_lgl`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_list <- list(c('a','b','c','d','e'),c('e','f','g'),c('h','i','j'))
names(my_list) <- c("group1","group2","group3")

expandg <- expand_grid(names(my_list), names(my_list))

pmap_lgl(expandg, ~ any(my_list[[.x]] %in% my_list[[.y]])) %>% 
  bind_cols(id1 = expandg[[1]], id2 = expandg[[2]], value = .) %>% 
  group_by(Group = id1) %>% summarise(value = any(value[id1 != id2]))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   Group  value
#>   <chr>  <lgl>
#> 1 group1 TRUE 
#> 2 group2 TRUE 
#> 3 group3 FALSE
```